# What am I wearing today?

Tags: knowledge, movies, literature

- Captain of serenity.
- Lover of Polish beast slayer.
- Sister of double victor.
- Foul-mouthed one-eyed soldier.
- Murgo-hating emperor.
- Owner of runaway bum.
- Fateful answerer of "What do you want?"
- Headmaster of Scandinavian school.
- Empress of southern rebels.
- Destroyer of the precious.
- Victim of black puddle.
- Queen of island foxes.
- Lonely pilot with gun.
- Blue djinn deputy.
- The last centurion.
- Husband of fallen star.

**What am I wearing today?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first bullet is rot13(Pncgnva Znypbyz Erlabyqf be Anguna Svyyvba sebz Sversyl)

Comment: None of these are video game references, right?

Comment: All of these fantasy references and no Wheel of Time?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Or maybe one of those you haven't solved yet is Wheel of Time. I'm not confirming either way :-)

Comment: The only one I can think of that would suit that is Queen of Island foxes...

Comment: I haven't watched The Game of Thrones or read a Song of Fire and Ice. Is Empress of Southern Rebels a reference to that?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Damn, I forgot GoT/aSoIaF. Should've included that. Nope.

Comment: How about the Sword of Truth Series, any of that in here?

Comment: @Joe-You-Knowpe.

Comment: ("one-eyed-soldier")

Comment: @Randal'Thor the only djinn I can think of whose name starts with I is Iblis, but I'm 98.45% sure that's not correct since he's neither blue nor a deputy. Is there any sort of non-giveaway hint you can provide on this last one?

Comment: @El-Guest The blue djinn is often deputising for a certain leader, whose friends include a boy with green skin and three warriors.

Comment: FINALLY I think I have it, @Joe-You-Know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Full Answer** (what I think the bullets mean)

Captain of serenity.

> Captain Malcolm Reynolds from Firefly, who is also the star in the movie Serenity.

Lover of Polish beast slayer.

> Yennefer of Vengerberg, wife of Geralt of Rivia (credit to  John Eisbrener) Now I know why I didn't get this one. Never played the Witcher series.

Sister of double victor.

> Primrose Everdeen from Hunger games. Credit to Richard.

Foul-mouthed one-eyed soldier.

> Richard says it could be Uno Nomesta instead though. He's probably right... Even though I want it to be Mat.

Murgo-hating emperor.

> From Richard, "Zakath hated the Murgos"

Owner of runaway bum.

> As Richard mentions, "Zack Freeman's bum went running off on its own."

Fateful answerer of "What do you want?"

> Londo Mollari from Babylon 5, thanks to Richard again.

Headmaster of Scandinavian school

> Igor Karkaroff, as Richard mentioned, is headmaster of Durmstrang. But is Durmstrang in Scandinavia?

Empress of southern rebels.

> Nasuada, from Eragon (Credit to Pugmonkey) Now that you mention it... This one makes a lot of sense.

Destroyer of the precious.

> Gollum from Lord of the Rings

Victim of black puddle.

> As Richard mentions, "Tasha Yar was killed by a black puddle."

Queen of island foxes.

> Silth, High Queen of Castle Marl from the Redwall novel Marlfox (Credit to El-Guest)

Lonely pilot with gun.

> Han Solo

Blue djinn deputy.

> As El-Guest figured out, the blue djinn is Ilwan, from the Never Ending Story.

The last centurion.

> Rory Williams from Doctor Who

Husband of fallen star.

> As Richard says, Tristan married Yvaine at the end of Stardust.

As Richard mentions (he really should get the credit) this spells out

> MY PUZZLING T SHIRT = My Puzzling T-Shirt

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83589/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-you-know-what-am-i-wearing-today).